# Rspec and_return sorts by id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

With the following rspec test:

```
@search_text = "California"
@search_condition = "location"
Video.stub_chain(:where,:order).and_return([@vid1,@vid2,@vid3])
Video.should_receive(:where).with("lower(#{@search_condition}) LIKE ?", "%#{@search_text}%".downcase)

return_val = Video.search(@search_text, @search_condition)
return_val.should == [@vid1,@vid2,@vid3]
```

That tests the following scope:

```
  scope :search, (lambda do |search_text, search_condition|
                where("lower(#{search_condition}) LIKE ?", "%#{search_text}%".downcase).order("name")
              end)
```

The value I get for return_value doesn't make the value I returned rom the stub_chain. Particularly, the items inside the array returned are the same but their order seems sorted by id and not by name. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Thanks!

Comment: This is far from being a spec, you're just testing your implementation which makes no sense. To spec a scope, create entries in db and see if you get the one you expect.

Comment: Yea i know that this test is redundant and I'm not using it anymore but it's just that this behavior was weird so I was wondering if anyone had an explanation of why it occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
unordered_videos = double "Video"
Video.should_receive(:where).with("lower(#{@search_condition}) LIKE ?", "%#{@search_text}%".downcase).and_return unordered_videos
unordered_videos.should_receive(:order).and_return [@vid1,@vid2,@vid3]
```

Comment: I mean, replace your current `stub` and `should` with thz above